# SQL. Get samples of data in group query

Tags: sql, random, group-by, google-bigquery, pivot

I have a simple table with only 2 columns:

```
| name | domain |
```

I need a SQL query to get this data:

```
| domain | names count | sample name 1 | ...2 | ...3 | ...4 | ...5 |
```

So, the first part is simple, just grouping by domain and getting names count. But the second part, **where I need to take 5 samples (they can be random) of names in the group** - I have no idea how to resolve it.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: I am using google bigquery. It supports the standard SQL dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT domain, names_count,
  samples[OFFSET(0)] AS sample_name_1,
  samples[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS sample_name_2,
  samples[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS sample_name_3,
  samples[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS sample_name_4,
  samples[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] AS sample_name_5
FROM (
  SELECT domain, 
    COUNT(name) names_count,
    ARRAY_AGG(name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) samples
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY domain
)
```

Comment: Thank you!
This query is working amazing even with 2B records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select
    domain,
    count(*) names_count,
    max(case when rn = 1 then name end) sample_name_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then name end) sample_name_2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then name end) sample_name_3,
    max(case when rn = 4 then name end) sample_name_4,
    max(case when rn = 5 then name end) sample_name_5
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by domaine order by rand()) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by domain
```

The subquery ranks `name`s having the same `domain` randomly. Then, the outer query aggregates by domain, and uses conditional aggregation to bring the first 5 randomly ranked names per group.